# c#: Global variable value changed even though it doesn't be assigned new value in a loop

Tags: c#, global-variables, variable-assignment, local-variables

Can anyone help explain why we get this result? What I expected result is "1,2".

```
        var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        List<List<int>> listStrs = new List<List<int>> { new List<int>{100,101 }, new List<int>{ 200, 201 } };
        foreach (var listStr in listStrs)
        {
            List<int> list2 = list1; //the way try to get expected result: List<int> list2 = list1.Select(i => i).ToList();
            list2.AddRange(listStr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",list1));
```

//result return: 1,2,100,101,200,201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` is a *reference type*. When you do the following:

```
 List<int> list2 = list1;
```

What you are actually doing is telling the compiler to make a copy of the value of the variable `list1` and assign it to `list2`. You must understand that variables are simply placeholders for *values*. In reference types, the *value* of the variable is the "address in memory" where the object "lives". Therefore, both `list2` and `list1` are "pointing" to (or referencing) the exact same object; there are two variables but one single list.

This is made obvious simply doing: `object.ReferenceEquals(list1, list2)`. It will return `true`.

`List<int> list2 = list1.Select(i => i).ToList();` works as you expect because the projection (`Select`) creates a *new* list. This new list and `list1` are altogether different instances and each "live" in different memory locations and are unrelated altogether; `object.ReferenceEquals(list1, list2)` wil return `false`.

Now, do bear in mind, that things change with *value types*. The value "stored" in a value typed variable is the instance itself; there are no references when it comes to value types (unless they are boxed).

Therefore, the following code:

```
struct EvilMutableStruct
{
    public int i
}

var e1 = new EvilMutableStruct();
var e2 = e1;
e2.i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(e1.i == 1); //prints false!
```

Why? Because, again, `e2 = e1` means the same; make a copy of the value stored in `e1` and assign it to `e2`. Because the value of `e1` is the value type instance itself, a copy of the object is made and stored in `e2`. Now both value typed variables hold two identical but *distinct* value type instances.